# Accessing JSON in state - ReactNative

Tags: json, react-native

For my ReactNative proejct: I'm currently trying to access a weather API and retrieve a .json file, store it in my state variable, and then access relevant objects within the .json file (ex: the current temperature, etc).

I'm able to access the entire .json file through my component's State. However, when I try to access objects (ex: current temperature), I get this error. I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct JSON key names to access it, so not sure what's wrong.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp_c' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {weatherResponse: []}; // the state of the App component

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=KEY&q=Paris')
      .then(
        function(response) {
          //console.log(response.data);
          this.setState({weatherResponse: response.data}); //here, I store the json file into the state.
        }.bind(this)
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.weatherResponse); //this works, no problem.
    console.log(this.state.weatherResponse.current.temp_c); //this returns the error below.
```

Here's the JSON file:

```
{
  "location": {
     "name": "Paris",
     "region": "Ile-de-France",
     "country": "France",
  },
  "current": {
     "last_updated_epoch": 1517616126,
     "last_updated": "2018-02-03 01:02",
     "temp_c": 2,
     "temp_f": 35.6,
     "is_day": 0,
     "cloud": 75
  }
}
```

Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: What is `cloud`? the json you posted doesn't have any such property. There's also a good chance that since `setState()` is asynchronous, `render` is executing before any data is stored in state.

Comment: updated the Json file to show that cloud exists, under "current" (I cropped the Json file in the post as it is very long). Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial render `this.state.weatherResponse` is empty, it only gets the data once your api request is completed and the state is updated. You should check whether `weatherResponse` contains the value before trying to access it.

Comment: Hey. So I thought this was the case - however, `console.log(this.state.weatherResponse)` or `console.log(this.state.weatherResponse.current)` returns what I'm looking for (i.e. the entire json object, see [here](https://gyazo.com/4e2669f3de9fec6131027fbb5682bc39), but `console.log(this.state.weatherResponse.current.temp_c)` gives me an error.

So I think there's something wrong with how I'm accessing temp_c, but I'm not sure where, any thoughts?

Comment: Figured this out - `this.state.weatherResponse` is empty in the initial render because `axios.get` is asynchronous, leading to errors. Adding a check to see if `weatherResponse` is empty fixed this.